# How to retry celery task on hard timeout?

Tags: python, celery

I have a celery task as follows:

```
@celery.task(name='tasks.ht_run', default_retry_delay=30, max_retries=15, time_limit=1)  
def ht_run(str_command):
    try:
        f = os.popen(str_command)
        output = f.read()
        if output == '':
            raise Exception
    except Exception as exc:
        raise ht_run.retry(exc=exc)

    return output.split('\n')
```

And it is called like so:
    appserver.ht_run.delay(string)

While I expect it to retry when it timeouts, instead if just fails.  In the Celery window I get the following error:

```
[2014-12-10 11:50:22,128: ERROR/MainProcess] Task tasks.ht_run[6a83793a-8bd6-47fc-bf74-0b673bf961f2] raised unexpected: TimeLimitExceeded(1,)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/andy.terhune/cgenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 639, in on_hard_timeout
    raise TimeLimitExceeded(job._timeout)
TimeLimitExceeded: TimeLimitExceeded(1,)
[2014-12-10 11:50:22,128: ERROR/MainProcess] Hard time limit (1s) exceeded for tasks.ht_run[6a83793a-8bd6-47fc-bf74-0b673bf961f2]
[2014-12-10 11:50:23,644: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'Worker-28' pid:2081 exited with 'signal 9 (SIGKILL)'
```

How can I get this to time out and retry when it does?

Comment: Is there any reason not to use a soft timeout?

Comment: have not tried it, i am fine with it as long as it retries

Answer (score 5):

Thanks  user2097159,

tried a soft timeout and worked like a charm,

```
@celery.task(
    name='tasks.ht_run', 
    default_retry_delay=30,
    max_retries=15,
    soft_time_limit=1)
def ht_run(str_command):
    try:
        f = os.popen(str_command)
        output = f.read()
        if output == '':
            raise Exception
    except Exception as exc:
        raise ht_run.retry(exc=exc)

    return output.split('\n')
```

...

```
[2014-12-10 12:16:55,580: WARNING/MainProcess] Soft time limit (1s) exceeded for tasks.ht_run[f31bbd15-e755-440c-9261-cd0864ceb3a9]
[2014-12-10 12:16:55,603: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: tasks.ht_run[f31bbd15-e755-440c-9261-cd0864ceb3a9] eta:[2014-12-10 18:17:25.593613+00:00]
[2014-12-10 12:16:55,603: DEBUG/MainProcess] basic.qos: prefetch_count->121
[2014-12-10 12:16:56,897: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.ht_run[f31bbd15-e755-440c-9261-cd0864ceb3a9] retry: Retry in 30s: SoftTimeLimitExceeded()
```

Comment: Just want to point out you shouldn't be using a generic `Exception`. The correct exception for the soft time out is `SoftTimeLimitExceeded`

Answer (score 4):

Now in version 4.0 you can specify [autoretry](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#automatic-retry-for-known-exceptions) for specific exceptions in the decorator. Here is an example from the documentation:

```
from twitter.exceptions import FailWhaleError

@app.task(autoretry_for=(FailWhaleError,))
def refresh_timeline(user):
    return twitter.refresh_timeline(user)
```

One of those exceptions can be `SoftTimeLimitExceeded` to satisfy your case.